# golang sql pointer values keep repeating itself

Tags: sql, pointers, go

Below is a golang function which is being called with an input channel

```
func getOptions(inChannel <-chan Param) <-chan ParamOptions {
    paramOptions := make(chan ParamOptions )

    go func() {
        defer close(paramOptions )
        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", wellConnStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("open connection failed:", err.Error())
        }

        defer conn.Close()

        getParamOptions := func(db *sql.DB, param *Param) {
            defer wg.Done()

            fmt.Println("querying options for ", param.Code, param.Name)

            rows, err := db.Query(`select *
                from dbo.ParamOptions where code=? and name=?`, &param.Code, &param.Name)

            fmt.Println("results for ", param.Name, param.Code)

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("query failed:", err.Error())
            }

            defer rows.Close()
            found := false

            ...

                paramOptions <- ParamOptions...

                break
            }

            if found == false {
                fmt.Println("did not find options for ", param.Code, param.Name)
            }
        }

        for paramInChannel := range paramChannel {
            wg.Add(1)
            fmt.Println("retrieving inputs for ", paramInChannel.Code, paramInChannel.Name)
            **go** getParamOptions(conn, &wellInChannel)
        }

        wg.Wait()
    }()

    return paramOptions 
}
```

If i remove the go keyword before calling the function getParamOptions it works without any problems. However if I use go then the last code and name keeps repeating within the the getParamOptions function, even though the options retrieved seems to be of the correct Param, the Code and Name values are being repeated

Comment: The provided code is not sufficient to determine where is the error. However, I doubt there is a data race. Try build it with the race detector and run it. `go build -race` and then run the execuatable.

Comment: Your code is incomplete so it's very difficult to debug it. But I feel like the `wg.Wait()` is causing issues here. Do you call it in your `getParamOptions` function? That would mean that `wg.Done` never gets `defer`ed and you're stuck in an endless loop.